# Формирование скрипта PostgreSQL из консольного окна

Tags: postgresql, debian, wsl

У меня есть бд в PostgreSQL. Мне необходимо сформировать скрипт этой бд из консольного окна WSL Debian

Comment: Что имеете ввиду, когда пишете "скрипт БД"? Скрипт, который будучи запущен на пустой БД восстановит схему и данные?

Comment: Да ............

Comment: А в чем нюанс с "консольный окном"? Имеете ввиду, что вам нужна команда для командной строки linux, которая это сделает?

Comment: Именно. Я не понимаю какой командой можно сформировать скрипт

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дамп базы в формате SQL делается командой `pg_dump`:

```
pg_dump -h имя_хоста_бд -U имя_пользователя_бд имя_базы > db.sql
```

сохранит дамп в `db.sql`.

Более подробно смотрите в [документации](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/app-pgdump.html), а тут есть [перевод](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgrespro/9.6/app-pgdump)

Comment: А где мне теперь искать этот файл?

Comment: В той директории, в которой запускалась команда.

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь